# Google Chrome Renders the same color code differently

Tags: css, google-chrome

Google Chrome Renders the same color code differently.please do check that product titles it uses the same color code as #7D0041
[image]

1.http://store.seaeagles.com.au/
2.http://turbo.oorjit.com/vbmr/seaeagles/

Answer (score 2):

I think that the color appears differently due to the [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing) used when rendering a smaller font. I took screenshots of the two pages and the core color is the same - 7D0041. But because the font is a smaller actual size on the second page it appears differently.

If you re-size the text on the second page so they are both are the same actual size (in pixels) the color appears identical.

Of course the 'works-on-my-machine' caveat applies :-)

Comment: In both Pages the font-size is 12px (actual size).

Comment: Okay - I've taken a quick look again and I think the culprit might be 'font-family: Calibri-Bold' which is referenced in the file index.scss on the second site. My eyes aren't perfect but I think it renders slightly lighter than the 'font-family: Calibri' that is used for the link text on the first site.

Comment: Is Calibri licenced for web use? My understanding is that it isn't.

Comment: Good point - I hadn't even thought of that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316785/calibri-font-commercial-usage